# How to get substring after specific substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, bots

I am making a bot to automatically answer to trivia questions. I am stuck at this point. I have the string of the question and I want to estrapolate it from the string with all the question of the Trivia.

In this example case, I have the string with the questions:

```
    var questions=`This was the first 3-D film*Bwana Devil
    This was the first cartoon talking picture*Steamboat Willie
    This was the sequel to "Star Wars"*The Empire Strikes Back`
```

I have a variable

```
    var str="This was the first cartoon talking picture"
```

And I need to find the string of str in the string with the question and get the part after the *, so

```
    "Steamboat Willie"
```

.

I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: You could you `str.split("*")[1].indexOf("Steamboat Willie")`

Comment: Wouldn't it give me this whole string "Steamboat Willie
    This was the sequel to "Star Wars"*The Empire Strikes Back`" ?  EDIT: Well I can't even use the answer "steamboat willie" because I don't know it yet. I am looking for that

Comment: I want only the answer of one question. I have one question and I need its answer, but if I split the string I will get also the other lines after the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your string is formatted with newlines between each question and answer pair:

### 1. Split the entire string by each newline:

`var questionAnswerStringPairs = string.split('\n');`

This will create an array of questions and answer strings. Each answer will be separated by an '*'.

### 2. Map over the resulting array, and create matching objects:

```
// This will store our data.
var questionAnswerPairs = {};

// Let's go through each string from step one and add the question and
// its answer to our object.
questionAnswerStringPairs.forEach( function(pair) {
  // split the string at the *
  pair = pair.split('*');

  // pair is now an array, the first element is the question string
  // the second element is the answer. Let's set those!
  var question = pair[0];
  var answer = pair[1];

  // now let's store that info in the object.
  questionAnswerPairs[question] = answer;
});
```

Now, you can do this:
`questionAnswerPairs['question i want the answer to']`, or this: `questionAnswerPairs[stringObjectWithQuestion]` and you will get back your answer!

Comment: This worked! Thanks, I had some problem with the missing ")" after the ending "}" and I was going insane. Really thanks, this is perfect

Comment: Thanks for the bug catch! Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

First split the questions, then filter them and finally get the answer

```js
var questions="This was the first 3-D film*Bwana Devil\nThis was the first cartoon talking picture*Steamboat Willie\nThis was the sequel to \"Star Wars\"*The Empire Strikes Back"
var str="This was the first cartoon talking picture"
    
var answers = questions
   .split("\n")
   .filter(question => question.indexOf(str) > -1)
   .map(question => question.substring(question.indexOf(str)+str.length+1))

alert(answers.join(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for( int i =0; i < questions.lenght;i++)
{
    var string = questions.split("*")[i].substring(0,"\n");
}
```

Would something like this work?

Comment: It would give me all the answer right? But I need only one, the one I am searching

Comment: In that case 'var string = questions.split("*")[2].substring(0,"\n");'

Comment: You would want to split from the asterisk to the end of the line ( "\n")